# Using Logical Operators in PHP if/else

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

Is it possible to use logical operators in the "then" part of the if/then statement in PHP?

This is my code:

```
if ($TMPL['duration'] == NULL) {
$TMPL['duration'] = ('120' or '124' or '114' or '138'); }
else {
$TMPL['duration'] = ''.$TMPL['duration']; }
```

Comment: What would be the logical meaning of you `then` statement ? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: use the pipe sign? `|`

Comment: I think he means `elseif`?

Comment: Not sure I understand... do you mean to combine multiple IF statements with OR (`||`)?

Comment: Sorry for not be that clear.  What I'm trying to do is if duration is equal to NULL, set duration equal to any of those numbers by choosing one at random.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `else if`.

```
$a = 1;

if($a === 1) {
    // do something
} else if ($a === 2) {
    // do something else    
}
```

Note that in most case the switch statement is better for that, like:

```
switch($a) {
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;

    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

or:

```
switch(TRUE) {
    case $a === 1 :
        // do something else    
        break;

    case $b === 2 :
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is if duration is equal to NULL, set duration equal to any of those numbers by choosing one at random. Is that possible?

Comment: use this: http://pastebin.com/6sNhh83G

Answer (score 0):

Are you aiming for a `switch`?

```
switch($TMPL['duration']) {
    case NULL:
    case '120':
    case '124':
    case '114':
    case '138':
        <do stuff>
        break;
    default:
        $TMPL['duration'] = ''.$TMPL['duration'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do something like this utilizing `in_array`:

```
if ($TMPL['duration'] === NULL
    || in_array($TMPL['duration'], array('120','124','114','138')) {
    // Do something if duration is NULL or matches any item in the array
} else {
    // Do something if duration is not NULL or does not match any item in array
}
```